# For loop to plyr function

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

I have a character array that holds the column names and values for a row in a data frame.  Unfortunately, if the value of a specific entry is zero, the column name and value are not listed in the array.  I create my desired data frame with this information, but I rely on a "for loop".

**I want to utilize [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) to avoid the for loop in the working code below.**

```
types <- c("one", "two", "three")      # My data
entry <- c("one(1)", "three(2)")       # My data


values <- function(entry, types)
{
  frame<- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = length(types), nrow = 1)), types)

  for(s1 in 1:length(entry))
  {
     name <- gsub("\\(\\w*\\)", "", entry[s1])                      # get name
     quantity <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(entry[s1], "[()]"))[2]) # get value

     frame[1, which(colnames(frame)==name)] <- quantity             # store

   }
   return(frame)
 }

 values(entry, types)                # This is how I want the output to look
```

I have tried the following to split the array, but **I can't figure out how to get adply to return a single row**.

```
types <- c("one", "two", "three")        # data
entry <- c("one(1)", "three(2)")         # data

frame<- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = length(types), nrow = 1)), types)    

array_split <- function(entry, frame){

  name <- gsub("\\(\\w*\\)", "", entry)                         # get name
  quantity <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(entry, "[()]"))[2])    # get value
  frame[1, which(colnames(frame)==name)] <- quantity            # store
  return(frame)
}

adply(entry, 1, array_split, frame)
```

**Is there something like cumsum I should be considering? I want to complete the operation quickly.**

Comment: Choosing to go to 'plyr' for speed is not generally advisable. If you have heard that loops are inefficient in R then you have been listening to the wrong advisors. Hadley has recently been developing 'dplyr' with performance in mind, but I do not think that was a major design goal for 'plyr'. 'plyr' as I see it was an effort to develop a unified grammar of transformations.

Comment: I'm afraid I often fall subject to poorly written loops, maybe using plyr makes me rethink things.  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2008-1.pdf has a pretty good section on efficient code writing, I'm going to try to keep these in mind more often.  Thank you for the dplyr tip too, it looks interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you aren't just doing something more like this:

```
frame <- setNames(rep(0,length(types)),types)
a <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(entry,"[()]"),`[[`,2))
names(a) <- gsub("\\(\\w*\\)", "", entry)
frame[names(a)] <- a
```

Both `gsub` and `strsplit` are already vectorized, so there's no real need for explicit loop anywhere. You only need the `sapply` to extract the second element of the `strsplit` results. The rest is just regular indexing.

Comment: This is great.  It didn't occur to me because I am not super comfortable with all of the different data types.  Thanks!

Also, in case others want to use this solution, to get it in my final format I needed to add "as.data.frame(t(frame)).